# Sklearn Pipelines - How to carry over PCA?

Tags: pca, gridsearchcv

I'm developing a pipeline to fit parameters for a gradient boosting classifier while also fitting the optimum number of features in a PCA model. This is the current setup:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('reduce_dim', PCA()),
    ('classify', GradientBoostingClassifier())
])
score = {'f1': 'f1', 'accuracy': 'accuracy'}
N_FEATURES_OPTIONS = [12,13,14,15]
max_dep = [3,4,5,6]
n_est = [50,80,100, 120, 150]
min_samp = [4,5,6,10]
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim': [PCA()],
        'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__n_estimators': n_est,
        'classify__max_depth': max_dep,
        'classify__min_samples_split':min_samp
    }]
reducer_labels = ['PCA']

grid_adc = GridSearchCV(pipe, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=score, refit='accuracy')
grid_adc.fit(X_train, y_train)
grid_adc.best_params_
```

Which outputs:

```
{'classify__max_depth': 3,
 'classify__min_samples_split': 4,
 'classify__n_estimators': 50,
 'reduce_dim': PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=12, random_state=None,
   svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False),
 'reduce_dim__n_components': 12}
```

Now I'd like to validate and score the model with cross validation. If I run the following:

```
cross_val_score(grid, X_train, y_train, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
```

Does the PCA I fit from the pipeline carry over to the cross_val_score function? If so, does the cross_val_score function transform the data with the PCA every time it generates a new train/test split?

Or do I need to create a new PCA after the pipeline to fit into the cross_val_score function?

Comment: In cross_val_score(grid, X_train, y_train, cv=5, n_jobs=-1) should you change grid for grid_adc?

Comment: Correct, that's a typo. I was cobbling together a few versions of this for the question.

Answer (score 2):

When doing GridSearchCv, the best model is already scored. You can access it with the attribute `best_score_` and get the model with `best_estimator_`. You do not need to re-score it in a cross validation.

Also, yes, the pipeline is entirely fitted when doing each split during the cv.